# App only C# code, does not work like the Graph explorer

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

In graph explorer:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/aebabbef-180f-49f6-92c9-be4201be286d/channels/19:6fe6827cc59d48558a21e7c6df64caec@thread.tacv2/messages
```

works fine I get a json with data.

The code snippets shows:

```
var messages = await graphClient.Teams["aebabbef-180f-49f6-92c9-be4201be286d"].Channels["19:6fe6827cc59d48558a21e7c6df64caec@thread.tacv2"].Messages
.Request()
.GetAsync();
```

So I use it as is in a console application With app only permission that has all the graph permissions but I get the error:

```
Code: UnknownError
Inner error:
        AdditionalData:
        date: 2021-01-24T20:03:02
        request-id: 9c294c0c-328a-4ca4-bcd0-1cbb3999dfd7
        client-request-id: 9c294c0c-328a-4ca4-bcd0-1cbb3999dfd7
ClientRequestId: 9c294c0c-328a-4ca4-bcd0-1cbb3999dfd7
```

anyone know what the error can be?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Ofer, if the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the List Channel Messages endpoint doesn't support App only permissions as shown below. Please check the [documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp). It works on the Graph Explorer because it gets the user token there.

[image]

Comment: So if I want to Copy / Move Messages from Team to Team, I have to do it as a user? Is there an example for this?

Comment: Yes, you could use this same code but with a user token. There are many [Authentication flows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-authentication-flows) you can follow. You can try this [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-devicecodeflow-v2) which follows Device Code flow. :)-